# sort list based on an instance variable java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a list of order objects. Each order object has 5 instance variables. Is there a way I can sort this list based on any of these instace variables?  I need to implement the comparable interface. But in that case, how could I sort on a specific variable?

Comment: What kind of variables are them? Primitives? If so, you just have to compare them in the compareTo method (you said you will implement the Comparable interface).

Comment: You mean multiple fields-order? Like SQL 'order by a,b,c'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `static` `Comparator`s in the class like this,

```
public static final Comparator<Order> NAME_COMPARATOR = Comparator<Order>(){
                              public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
                                  // provide an impl here using order name
                              }
                          }

public static final Comparator<Order> ID_COMPARATOR = Comparator<Order>(){
                              public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
                                  // provide an impl here using order id
                              }
                          }
```

And then pass those while sorting like this,

```
Collections.sort(list, Order.NAME_COMPARATOR);
Collections.sort(list, Order.ID_COMPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a lot of ambiguity.  Here's an example of a 5-field class.  This class is sortable using `Comparable`, which in this case sorts by field `a`, then field `b`, and if `a` and `b` are identical, the two are equivalent in sort order.  If you implement [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), you probably also need to implement `equals()` and ensure that it is consistent, as demanded in the `Comparable` interface spec.  See also [javapractices.com "implementing `compareTo()`"](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) for some good detail.

Working example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class SortableThing implements Comparable<SortableThing>
{
  final String foo;
  final int a, b, c, d, e;

  public SortableThing(String foo, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
  {
    this.foo = foo;   this.a = a;
    this.b = b;       this.c = c;
    this.d = d;       this.e = e;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(SortableThing o)
  {
    if (this.a != o.a) 
      return this.a - o.a;
    else if (this.b != o.a)
      return this.b - o.b;
    else return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if (!(o instanceof SortableThing)) return false;
    SortableThing st = (SortableThing)o;
    return st.a == this.a && st.b == this.b;
  }

  @Override 
  public String toString()
  {
    return new StringBuilder().append(foo).append(": <").append(a)
     .append(',').append(b)
     .append(',').append(c)
     .append(',').append(d)
     .append(',').append(e).append('>').toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final SortableThing one, two, three, four;
    one = new SortableThing("one", 4, 2, 42, 42, 42);
    two = new SortableThing("two", 2, 3, 42, 42, 42);
    three = new SortableThing("three", 2, 2, 42, 42, 42);
    four = new SortableThing("four", 1, 50, 42, 42, 42);
    SortableThing[] list = new SortableThing[] {one,two,three,four};
    System.out.println("Before: "+Arrays.deepToString(list));
    Arrays.sort(list);
    System.out.println("After: "+Arrays.deepToString(list));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Before: [one: <4,2,42,42,42>, two: <2,3,42,42,42>, three: <2,2,42,42,42>, four: <1,50,42,42,42>]
After: [four: <1,50,42,42,42>, three: <2,2,42,42,42>, two: <2,3,42,42,42>, one: <4,2,42,42,42>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty elegantly in Scala.

```
val sortedOrders = orders.sortBy(o => (o.a, o.b, o.c))
```

Sorts the `orders` list by the the field `a` first, then by field `b`, and then by field `c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'order by a,b,c', I wrote a blog to solve it: [对java.util.List多字段排序](http://blog.csdn.net/michaellufhl/archive/2010/10/01/5917686.aspx). See 2nd snippet of code, sorry it' Chinese, but code and comment are English:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have "get" methods for the instance variables you can use a [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) so you don't have to write custom code.

Comment: Explain the downvote? Give reasons so people can make up their own mind.

Comment: But i need to sort both in english and german..... Is it possible with this Class?